# how to unset a session variable?

Tags: php

I have the following code, but it does not work, I don't know what mistake I am committing due to which this code does not work:

Here is the code:

```
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_GET['indexNo']) && is_numeric($_GET['indexNo']) && !empty($_GET['indexNo'])) 
{
   $indx = $_GET['indexNo'];
   foreach($_SESSION['itemsOrder'] as $key => $val)
{
 echo "$key => $val <br> " ;    
  if($indx == $val)
  {
    unset($_SESSION['itemsOrder'][$val]);

  }
  else
  {

    echo "indexNo was not unset <br>";
  }
 }
}
else 
{
    echo "indexNo not received!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be `$key` not the `$val` . Try with -

```
if($indx == $key)
{
    unset($_SESSION['itemsOrder'][$key]);

}
```

No need to use `isset` & `empty` together.

```
if (isset($_GET['indexNo']) && is_numeric($_GET['indexNo']))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to unset the session array value than you must use its key instead of value.
replaced:

```
unset($_SESSION['itemsOrder'][$val]);
```

with:

```
unset($_SESSION['itemsOrder'][$key]);
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur, I'll try it.

Comment: You can appreciate on stacks by accepting answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try This Code**
<?php session_start();
if (isset($_GET['indexNo']) && is_numeric($_GET['indexNo'])) 
{
$indx = $_GET['indexNo'];
foreach($_SESSION['itemsOrder'] as $key => $val)
{
echo "$key => $val <br> " ; 
if($indx == $val)
{
    unset($_SESSION['itemsOrder'][$key]);

}
else
{

    echo "indexNo was not unset <br>";
}
}
}
else 
{
    echo "indexNo not received!";
}
```